# What are the tuning parameters available for Oracle BPEL PM

Tags: performance, bpel

Are there any tuning knobs that one can apply for Oracle BPEL Process Manager?

Answer (score 0):

There is no single GUI from where you can tune Oracle `BPEL PM.` While the Administration and configuration tabs allow you to tune a few parameters, most are in XML config files. Have a look at [this](http://download-west.oracle.com/docs/cd/B32110_01/core.1013/b28942/tuning_bpel.htm).